# XML Parent and Child Attributes and Elements in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a some XML data that has a lot of attributes and multiple elements with the same name and I want to flatten it out into a CSV file. The data XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SEGMENTS>
    <SEGMENT NAME="webcluster">
        <RESULTPAGE>
            <RESULTSET FIRSTHIT="1" LASTHIT="100" HITS="100" TOTALHITS="100">
                <HIT NO="1" RANK="19000" SITEID="0" MOREHITS="100">
                    <FIELD NAME="rank">19000</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="id">1</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="url">C:\website.com\folder1\file1.txt</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="filename">file1.txt</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="path">https://website.com/folder1/</FIELD>
                </HIT>
                <HIT NO="2" RANK="19000" SITEID="0" MOREHITS="100">
                    <FIELD NAME="rank">19000</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="id">2</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="url">C:\website.com\folder1\file2.txt</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="filename">file2.txt</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="path">https://website.com/folder1/</FIELD>
                </HIT>
                <HIT NO="3" RANK="18999" SITEID="0" MOREHITS="100">
                    <FIELD NAME="rank">18999</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="id">3</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="url">C:\website.com\folder5\file3.txt</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="filename">file3.txt</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="path">C:\website.com\folder\</FIELD>
                </HIT>
            </RESULTSET>
        </RESULTPAGE>
    </SEGMENT>
</SEGMENTS>
```

And I'm trying to iterate through it to produce something like this

> ```
> HIT    filename    path  
> -----  ----------  ------  
> 1      file1.txt   C:\website.com\folder1\  
> 2      file2.txt   C:\website.com\folder1\  
> 3      file3.txt   C:\website.com\folder5\
> ```

My code is:

```
[xml]$xml=Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml  
$hits = $xml.segments.segment.resultpage.resultset.hit  
foreach($hit in $hits)  
{  
    foreach($field in $hit.field)  
    {  
        if (field."NAME" -eq 'url')  
        {  
            write-output $hit.no $field."#VALUE"  
        }  
    }  
}
```

And I keep getting errors. I can access the different elements and attributes by referencing them by ordinal location ($hits[0].field[4]) but I want to protect against future output where the FIELD values might be in a different order.

Can anyone suggest how I can get this done? I tried using select-XML and found that to be even more troublesome, but maybe that's the more elegant method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems to do it, although i don't like that.

```
[xml]$xml=Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml  
$hits = $xml.segments.segment.resultpage.resultset.hit  
foreach($hit in $hits)  
{  
    $result = new-object PSObject -Property @{ hit = $hit.no; filename = ""; path = ""}

    foreach($field in $hit.field)  
    {  
        if ($field."NAME" -eq 'url')  
        {  
            $result.path = $field."#text"
        }  
        if ($field."NAME" -eq 'filename')
        {
            $result.filename = $field."#text"
        }
    }  
    write-output $result
}
```

or, just grabbing all fields, and then selecting relevant:

```
[xml]$xml=Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml  
$hits = $xml.segments.segment.resultpage.resultset.hit  
foreach($hit in $hits)  
{  
    $result = new-object PSObject -Property @{ hit = $hit.no }
    $hit.field | % { Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_."NAME" -Value $_."#text"}  
    $result | select hit,url,filename | write-output
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Someone offline suggested:
`[xml]$hitfile = Get-Content fastxml.xml  
`foreach($hit in $hitfile.segments.segment.resultpage.resultset.hit)  
`{  
`     $row = $mjatable.NewRow()  
`     $row.Hit = $hit.No
`     $row.InternalID = $hit.field | ?{$_.name -eq 'Internalid'} | foreach {$_.'#text'}
`     $row.URL = $hit.field | ?{$_.name -eq 'url'} | foreach {$_.'#text'}
`     $mjaTable.Rows.Add($row)
`} 
`$mjaTable | format-table -AutoSize

Comment: I'm still curious if it's possible to ref a FIELD element with NAME attrib = ("url" or "Internalid") and retrieve '#text" value without using the WHERE-OBJECT filter, but if not, these two solutions get the job done.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//HIT' | Foreach {
    $num=$_.Node.NO
    $filenameAttr = $_.Node.Field | where {$_.Name -eq 'filename'}
    $pathAttr = $_.Node.Field | where {$_.Name -eq 'path'}
    new-object psobject -Property ([ordered]@{HIT=$num; filename = $filenameAttr.InnerText; path = $pathAttr.InnerText})
}
```

Comment: Keith, trying the code above I get:  
    Unable to find type [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.  
    At line:6 char:45
    +     new-object psobject -Property ([ordered] <<<< @{HIT=$num; filename = $filenameAttr.InnerText; path = $pathAttr.InnerText})  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ordered:String) [], RuntimeException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

I'll try some modifications

Comment: Ah, that is new to PowerShell V3. You can remove that but the order of properties in the created object will be random.

Answer (score 0):

combining approaches. Select allows to get fields in a particular order.

```
[xml]$xml=Get-Content .\xmlfile.xml  
$hits = $xml.segments.segment.resultpage.resultset.hit  
foreach($hit in $hits)  
{  
    $r = @{hit = $hit.no; url = "N/A";filename="N/A"}
    $hit.field | % { $r[$_."NAME"] = $_."#text" }  
    New-Object PSObject -Property $r | Select hit,url,filename
}
```